# KR512 internal circuitry

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

The KR512 is claimed to be equivalent to the MK5009, but it clearly isn't - the pinout is different, for a start. Does anyone know what the internal logic looks like? The thing clearly has a RC oscillator and some counting circuitry, but is it selectable, like the MK5009, or fixed? The published diagram is far too vague to be useful, and I have not found a specification. For comparison, the Mostek MK5009 is at https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/612322/Mostek/MK5009/1

[image]

Comment: Link to both device data sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I have now measured some of these devices and created a crude datasheet. I am still searching for a suitable place to lodge this, and I will update this answer when available.

In summary, the device has a peculiar divider system, with a fixed divisor followed by a selectable additional divisor. The oscillator section is also strange. It is clearly designed for a particular application, and cannot be considered as a universal component - unlike the MK5009.

EDIT: The PDF is available at https://github.com/henros32/KR512